# *** not exported by package *** golang

Tags: vscode, go

Estoy intentando utilizar modulos en go pero el visual studio code me da este error al intentar ejecutar la funcion del package.

Paquete main

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "mymodule/mypackage"
    )
    
    func main() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello World!")
        mypackage.hello()
    }
```

```golang
//mypackage

package mypackage

import "fmt"

func hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello noodles")
}
```

go.mod file

```golang
module mymodule

go 1.17
```

el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Hola Arturo como estas?

El problema que tienes es que Golang define la visibilidad en base a lexicografía.

El concepto de visibilidad esta relacionado con un campo, función, método o paquete y esta definido por la primer letra.

La primer letra mayúscula define la visibilidad Pública, la primer letra minúscula define la visibilidad privada.

La solución en este caso es cambiar tu método hello() de myPackage por Hello ().

```
//mypackage

package mypackage

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello noodles")
}
```